# Google DNS doesn't work

Tags: network, wifi, mojave, dns

I have trouble using Google DNS under my 2017 MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave.. I want to point in advance that:

1. I don't have access to the router settings.
2. I'm using kind of host network that my landlord provided to me. I would like to avoid to contact him.

I can ping the DNS server I want to use:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8 
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes 64 bytes from
8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=120 time=11.034 ms
```

I can resolve names without Google DNS:

```
$ nslookup www.apple.com
Server:     192.168.179.1
Address:    192.168.179.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.apple.com   canonical name = www.apple.com.edgekey.net.
www.apple.com.edgekey.net   canonical name = www.apple.com.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net.
www.apple.com.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net    canonical name = e6858.dsce9.akamaiedge.net.
Name:   e6858.dsce9.akamaiedge.net
Address: 184.25.247.151
```

I cannot resolve names with Google DNS:

```
$ nslookup www.apple.com 8.8.8.8
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Setting up the DNS addresses in a new location does not help.

Comment: It's entirely possible that your landlord is blocking outgoing DNS traffic at the router/firewall.  I was just able to replicate your problem by dropping outbound DNS traffic to anywhere except my ISP's DNS.  To test this, use a different network (a hotspot is perfect) and try your `nslookup`.  If it works, it's the router/firewall

Comment: @Allan You are probably right. I didn't try with an hotspot, but I tried to monitor the traffic with wireshark. Apparently the DNS traffic is dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make a network setting and override the dns on each Mac easily given that the dns isn’t blocked on the network and is just not chosen / advertised.

Google has steps - scroll down to macOS section: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

I also encourage you to try cloudflare dns. Setup is just as easy and the config app and setup screens are easier for me to recommend, and you could sub the google values as you please if this setup guide is simpler:

- https://1.1.1.1/dns/